# Jquery prepend html syntax error " and '

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´d like to prepend a div with an onClick function via jQuery like that:

```
var myFirstDivChange =  '<div class="myClass" onClick="changemyvariable('4v5');">MyText</div>',

$('#myDiv').prepend(myFirstDivChange);
```

This is the changemyvariable function:

```
function changemyvariable (mynewvariable) {
var myoldvariable = mynewvariable

}
```

It does not work and returns

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
changemyvariable(
```

Is there a problem with " or ' ? If i try it like "4v5" it does not work either..

Comment: you have `'` within `'`.

Comment: You need to escape the internal single quotes here as `changemyvariable(\'4v5\')` but really you ought to be binding that event dynamically rather than coding it into the markup.

Comment: Conside using [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to bind the event rather than hard-coding it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to quote the single-quotes in your HTML string:

```
var myFirstDivChange =  '<div class="myClass" onClick="changemyvariable(\'4v5\');">MyText</div>',
```

You'd be better off adding with jQuery, since you're using the library anyway:

```
$('#mydiv').prepend($('<div/>', {
  text: "MyText"
, "class": "myClass"
, click: function() { changemyvariable("4v5"); }
}));
```

Same effect, but less messy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the quotes

```
'<div class="myClass" onClick="changemyvariable(\'4v5\');">MyText</div>'
```